# Error When Inserting Data Into Table (UUID)

Tags: postgresql, pentaho-data-integration

I am getting an error " ERROR: column "u_id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying" when trying to insert data in my table. I recently created a UUID field in my table. How can i fix this error? I am using pentaho data integration to load the data into my tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Pentaho, unfortunately and 1 day after creation of the question, it seems very few people would be able to help you.
Do you have a way to cast data in Pentaho?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (('some-valid-uuid')::uuid)
```